Joining temporal table with tumbling window aggregation based on geospatial proximity
I'm trying to join station status data with weather updates in Flink SQL. The goal is to:

Calculate average status metrics for each station in 1-minute windows
Join this with weather data based on timestamp and geographical proximity

This is a rough diagram of what I want to achieve:

So far I have managed to perform the aggregation over dock_status_update and joined with bike_station, but the subsequent join with weather_update the one I am not getting right.
This is my query so far:
SELECT
    a.station_id,
    b.name AS station_name,
    b.latitude,
    b.longitude,
    a.average_available_docks,
    a.window_start,
    a.window_end,
    w.`timestamp`,
    w.temperature,
    w.humidity
FROM (
    SELECT 
        station_id, window_start, window_end, 
        AVG(available_docks) AS average_available_docks 
    FROM 
        TABLE(TUMBLE(TABLE dock_status_update, 
        DESCRIPTOR(`timestamp`), 
        INTERVAL '1' MINUTES))
    ) 
    GROUP BY 
    station_id, 
    window_start, 
    window_end
) a
JOIN bike_stations b ON a.station_id = b.station_id
LEFT JOIN weather_update FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF a.window_end w
    ON CAST(w.latitude * 100 AS INT) = CAST(b.latitude * 100 AS INT)
    AND CAST(w.longitude * 100 AS INT) = CAST(b.longitude * 100 AS INT);

However, I am getting this error:
org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Temporal table join currently only supports 'FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF' left table's time attribute field

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Instead of window_end, try using window_time. That might work, but I have some doubts. window_time is basically the same thing as window_end, but with watermarking defined on it, which allows this field to be used for subsequent temporal operations that require watermarks.
The reason for my doubts is that I don't believe regular JOINs allow time attributes to pass through them -- let us know what you find. You might need to transform this join into a temporal join, by adding a somewhat superfluous time attribute to the bike_stations table.
Another solution would be to adapt the UNION ALL strategy described  here.
